# Help finding a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble coming up with a basis but il show all my work,

I want to find a basis to the orthogonal complement of the matrix Q= $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$

for matrices in $\mathbb M_{2x2}$ with inner product $(X,Y)=tr(Y^{T}X)$

What I have done;;

I wrote $Q^\perp$=$\{Q* \in \mathbb M_2x2 : (Q,Q*)=0\}$

Letting $Q*=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \\ \end{bmatrix}$

and setting equal to zero I get that we must have $a-c+d=0$ but how can I turn that into a basis? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hin**t:

You have that $c = a+d \Rightarrow Q_{*} = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ a+d & d \end{pmatrix}= a\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} + b\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} + d\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. Can you see the basis now?

Comment: Yes thanks that makes sense.  A basis could be those 3 matrices for example

Comment: That is true, the $3$ matrices that you saw make the basis for $Q_{*}$.

Comment: Just clarifying, its dim 3 right?

Answer (score 0):

You found the condition $a-c+d=0$, which means that $c=a+d$ so just set:

$\begin{bmatrix}
       a & b           \\[0.3em]
       c & d
     \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
       a & b           \\[0.3em]
       a+d & d
     \end{bmatrix}=a\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 0           \\[0.3em]
       1 & 0
     \end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 1           \\[0.3em]
       0 & 0
     \end{bmatrix}+d\begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0           \\[0.3em]
       1 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}$

Where $a,b,d\in\mathbb{R}$. I'll let you draw the conclusions from this.